# D3js single horizontal bar with three colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to make a d3js version 5 horizontal bar with three colors 60% red, 30% yellow and 10% green. Any ideas?

I am not sure if I have to create three rect elements and align them or create one rect and try to change the colors with CSS properties. I dont want to use gradient...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.first {
  fill: #ffff00;
}
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
  var svgWidth = 600, svgHeight=400;
  scaleFactor = 20;

  var data = [100];

  var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 300]);

  var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
       return "translate(0," + scaleFactor + ")";
    });

     bar.append("rect")
     .attr("class", "first")
     .attr("width", function(d) {
      return d;
    })         
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("rx", 25)
    .attr("ry", 25);  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with a gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place rectangles sequentially one method we can use is to specify the properties of each bar if we know them beforehand:

```
var data = [
  { start: 90, end: 100, color: "lightgreen" },
  { start: 60, end: 90, color: "yellow" },
  { start: 0, end: 60, color: "crimson" }
];
```

With three items in the data array, we can use an enter selection to place three rectangles in the SVG.

We could programmatically derive the start and end information based on the provided numebrs too, 60,30,10, with some manipulation, but for demonstration I'll just use the above data array:

```js
var svgWidth = 600, svgHeight=400;
  scaleFactor = 20;

var data = [
  { start: 90, end: 100, color: "lightgreen" },
  { start: 60, end: 90, color: "yellow" },
  { start: 0, end: 60, color: "crimson" }
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", svgWidth)
 .attr("height", svgHeight);


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.end; })])
  .range([0, 300]);


var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(0," + scaleFactor + ")");
    
bar.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "first")
 .attr("width", function(d) {
   return x(d.end - d.start);  // get the width
 }) 
 .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.start);        // get the start position
 })
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
 .attr("height", 20);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

*If you really want the rounding we could use a clip path - as a `rect`s rx and ry attributes are applied on all corners:*

```js
var svgWidth = 600, svgHeight=400;
  scaleFactor = 20;

var data = [
  { start: 90, end: 100, color: "lightgreen" },
  { start: 60, end: 90, color: "yellow" },
  { start: 0, end: 60, color: "crimson" }
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", svgWidth)
 .attr("height", svgHeight);


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.end; })])
  .range([0, 300]);


var clip = svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id","clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 300) // width
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("rx", 12)
  .attr("ry", 12);


var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(0," + scaleFactor + ")");
    
bar.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "first")
 .attr("width", function(d) {
   return x(d.end - d.start);  // get the width
 }) 
 .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.start);        // get the start position
 })
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
 .attr("height", 20)
 .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

*If you really want to use css rather than d3 to style the rectangles you could either specify an identifier to color the bars or use standard css selectors such as `nth-of-type`:*

```js
var svgWidth = 600, svgHeight=400;
  scaleFactor = 20;

var data = [
  { start: 90, end: 100, id: "green"},
  { start: 60, end: 90, id: "yellow"},
  { start: 0, end: 60, id: "red"}
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", svgWidth)
 .attr("height", svgHeight);


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.end; })])
  .range([0, 300]);


var clip = svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id","clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 300) // width
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("rx", 12)
  .attr("ry", 12);


var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(0," + scaleFactor + ")");
    
bar.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "first")
 .attr("width", function(d) {
   return x(d.end - d.start);  // get the width
 }) 
 .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.start);        // get the start position
 })
 .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
 .attr("height", 20)
 .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");
```

```css
#green {
  fill: lightgreen;
}

#red {
  fill: crimson;
}

#yellow {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew you saved my day

Comment: No problem, glad to help.